# Incompatible magic value 21877456 in class file

Tags: java, windows, iis, applet

Im trying to use java applet on my web page. I try/search lots of thing but no chance. So here is the case.

My applet code is simple in app.html :

```
    <applet codebase="." archive="applet.jar" code="de.escape.quincunx.dxf.apViewer" width="640" height="480" name="TEST">
    <param name="file"               value="40.dxf">
    <param name="framed"             value="false">
    <param name="frameWidth"         value="800">
    <param name="frameHeight"        value="600">
    </applet>
```

This html file is working when i directly open in browser. Its working when i serve it with apache but its not working and give error "Incompatible magic value 21877456 in class file" when i try to serve with IIS. In apache i try php and html, both is working.

Is there any special configuration need on IIS when i try to serve applet?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think IIS is not serving the right file for a .class, probably it is returning a 404 error or something similar, since it cannot find the file.

That error means that Java was expecting a .class file, all class files start with 0xCAFEBABE, which is a magic number with which Java can check that the file it is receiving is in fact a class file. In your case, however, the file returned by IIS is not a class file, it does not start with 0xCAFEBABE, and Java is unable to parse it.

The most common reason for it is that the web server is not able to serve the file, often because of a 404 error.

You should check what happens under the hood, search in IIS logs for requests of .class files, or use a tool (maybe even firebug) to see what is returned to the browser.

Comment: IIS also won't serve a file that it doesn't have a configured content type for. Make sure you have a string value called "Content Type" in your registry for HLKM\System\Classes\.jar - the correct value seems to be ["application/x-java-archive"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format))

Comment: I guess you are talking about HKLM\Software\Classes, i check that and there was no content type string for .jar and i added but there is nothing changed but thank you for reply i'm looking more deeply. Actually i'm sure i'm not the only person who see this, there must some other people exist who use IIS and serve applets. I will wait another replies while investigating more.

Comment: @Simone Gianni, if it's related about Mime Types do you know what is the right mime type for .jar and .class? I try to put mime types which in the Apache mime types but nothing changed (it was application/java-archive for .jar and application/java-vm for .class).In the iis logs java try to get "/de/escape/quincunx/ap/reader/apVPORT.class" and this is where error appears.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution. Actually its not the exact solution but thank you for your answer Simone Gianni. His answer lead me to deeply search in IIS access logs and compare them with APACHE access logs. And yes, both was same and looks like couple of classes are not in place in the JAR file. So apVPORT.class is not in the jar file and developer who wrote this applet leave the calls for those classes in the other part of applet even he is not using them.

If someone can answer the reason why apache don't send any information or "its okey" information to java and continue loading rest of the applet even it see the 404 for apVPORT.class but IIS send 404 to java, this will be the final answer for this question.

Comment: "couple of classes are not in place in the JAR file" - doesn't Apache just serve the .jar file, though, and not the individual classes? Do you have access logs for apache that show a request for the individual .class? What response code is it giving?

Comment: did you read only that part of my message? since i already mention about apache and iis logs, both are same; "both was same and looks like couple of classes are not in place in the JAR file" its 404 for apVPORT.class forexample, in the iis and apache logs.

Comment: I didn't understand your last bit about sending "it's OK", and you said 'but' in "apache sees 404 *but* IIS sends 404" so it sounding like something different was actually happening. I was just trying to clarify what your question actually was. Why would apache know that a missing file was OK?

Comment: Behaviour is weird, that is why its hard to explain. Let me try to explain different way. Im using same JAR on IIS and Apache. On IIS java gives error while trying to run applet because its see some files in the JAR is not there (forexample in the logs apVPORT.class is return 404). This is the exact error (Incompatible magic value) when java cant find the file or requested file returned 404 to JAVA. And on the Apache same thing happening (in the apache logs apVPORT.class is return 404) but applet is working without any error.

Rest of the comments are only my toughts on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Incompatible magic value 21877456 in class file : I found that this error comes when page is not able to reach /read the jar file.

in aspx page -

```
   <applet code="FileAccess.class"
   archive="../applet/SignFileAccessApplet.jar" width="325" height="325">  
   </applet>
```

in archive check whether url is proper or not by using "pickurl" option provided by intellisense of Visual Studio.
class file path in jar file need to be given in code attribute.